# How to build Docker images based on containers?

Tags: docker

I would like to build a Docker image, using a container as base image. 
Does anyone have any idea about how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) the container and use it with the [`FROM`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) directive in the Dockerfile of the image you intend to build.

Comment: In my case, I'm just making another tag from the same image. I can't see why I have to change the FROM directive, but indeed, docker commit [docker commit CONTAINER_ID repo/image:tag] is the one to do this job. 

Thank you @dawud :)!

Answer (score 1):

To build a container from the image "ImageName" you can create a file named ~/Dockerfile with the contents

```
FROM ImageName 
MAINTAINER "Author Name"
ENV REFRESHED_AT 2015-10-13
```

## Create the new Docker image

```
sudo docker build -t "NewImageName" ~/Dockerfile
```

## Generate the container instance

```
sudo docker run --name container_name --privileged=true -d -i NewImageName /sbin/init*
```